# ImportError: No module named py4j.java_gateway

Tags: java, python, eclipse, py4j

I am trying to test calling a java program from Python using `py4j`. I have installed the plugin in Eclipse and created pydev project named test. I am trying to execute the following piece of code I found on the py4j webpage:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway, java_import

gateway = JavaGateway()
jvm = gateway.jvm

java_import(jvm, 'org.eclipse.core.resources.*')

workspace_root = jvm.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
gateway.help(workspace_root, '*Projects*')

project_names = [project.getName() for project in workspace_root.getProjects()]
print(project_names)
```

But I get an error in the import. I have checked that the py4j jar is present in the plugins directory of Eclipse. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the py4j application from http://py4j.sourceforge.net/install.html#install-instructions